# How to pass arrays in OOP PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I want to pass an array from the class Database to the class Characters, someone can help me?

**My Code:**

*Class Database*

```
class Database {

  public function DBCharactersMerchandise() {

    $db = $this->connection();

    $uid = $_SESSION['id'];

    $this->conn = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mercadoria WHERE cid = :mid");
    $this->conn->execute(array(':mid' => $uid));

    while($row = $this->conn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $array = [

            $row['type'], // here I have 'apple' and 'orange'

        ];

        return $array;

    }

 }   
}
```

*Class Characters*

```
Class Characters {

    public function getUserMerchandise() {

       $db = new Database();
       $type = $db->DBCharactersMerchandise();

       foreach ($type as $value) {

         echo $value; // I want echo 'apple' and 'orange' here

       }

  }
}
```

I think you can understand what I want, so I someone could help me I appreciate.

Comment: I spot a possible problem where you do `return $array;` in your class `Database`

Comment: You can try looking into [dependency injection](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Dependency-Injection-in-PHP-example-how-to-DI-create-your-own-dependency-injection-container).  It sounds like a good fit for your use case.

Comment: do you need the `type` field values only?

Comment: yes @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: You could also just select the row `type`, then use `fetchAll` and return the result. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: `$this->conn = $db->prepare("SELECT type FROM mercadoria WHERE cid = :mid"); $this->conn->execute(array(':mid' => $uid)); return $this->conn->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the array in the while loop, and then return it after the while loop is completed

```
class Database {

    public function DBCharactersMerchandise() {

        $db = $this->connection();    
        $uid = $_SESSION['id'];

        $this->conn = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mercadoria` WHERE `cid` = :mid");
        $this->conn->execute(array(':mid' => $uid));

        $array = [];

        while($row = $this->conn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $array[] = $row['type'];
        }
        return $array;    
    }   
}
```

Or better still select just what you want to use, this will speed up the query, then you can use `->fetchAll` to load a complete result array ready to return

```
class Database {

    public function DBCharactersMerchandise() {

        $db = $this->connection();    
        $uid = $_SESSION['id'];

        $this->conn = $db->prepare("SELECT `type` FROM `mercadoria` WHERE `cid` = :mid");
        $this->conn->execute(array(':mid' => $uid));

        $array = $this->conn->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        return $array;    
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php)?

```php
class Database {

  public function DBCharactersMerchandise() {

    $db = $this->connection();

    $uid = $_SESSION['id'];

    $this->conn = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mercadoria WHERE cid = :mid");
    $this->conn->execute(array(':mid' => $uid));

    while($row = $this->conn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $array = [

            $row['type'], // here I have 'apple' and 'orange'

        ];

        yield $array;

    }

 }   
}

class Characters {

    public function getUserMerchandise() {

       $db = new Database();

       foreach ($db->DBCharactersMerchandise() as $value) {

         echo $value; // I want echo 'apple' and 'orange' here

       }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The optimized version using `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` flag to fetch values from the needed field only:

```
class Database {

    public function DBCharactersMerchandise() {

        $db = $this->connection();
        $this->conn = $db->prepare("SELECT type FROM mercadoria WHERE cid = :mid");
        $this->conn->execute(array(':mid' => $_SESSION['id']));

        return $this->conn->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }

}

Class Characters {

    public function getUserMerchandise() {

        $db = new Database();
        $types = $db->DBCharactersMerchandise();

        if (!empty($types) && is_array($types)) {
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                echo $type;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per your question what I can see is return should be outside while loop.

Comment: I already try it, dont work because i have multiple variables

Comment: What does that mean "Multiple variable"?